# How to convert my code ( this.state ) into useState()?

Tags: reactjs

I need to convert the following code into a stateless functional component, without using a class. Unfortunately I'm not very good at interpreting class based components as functional components so I'm not sure exactly what the syntax would be.

```
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isOpen: true,
        };
  }

    render() {
        return (
            <IconSettings iconPath="/assets/icons">
                {this.state.isOpen ? (
                    <AlertContainer>
                        <Alert
                            dismissible
                            icon={<Icon category="utility" name="user" />}
                            labels={{
                                heading: 'Logged in as John Smith (johnsmith@acme.com).',
                                headingLink: 'Log out',
                            }}
                            onClickHeadingLink={() => {
                                console.log('Link clicked.');
                            }}
                            onRequestClose={() => {
                                this.setState({ isOpen: false });
                            }}
                        />
                    </AlertContainer>
                ) : null}
            </IconSettings>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies; I changed the code block to include the context.

Comment: Suggested reading material is [Using the State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use a functional component, try this example:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);

  return (
    <IconSettings iconPath="/assets/icons">
      {isOpen ? (
         <AlertContainer>
            <Alert
                dismissible
                icon={<Icon category="utility" name="user" />}
                labels={{
                  heading: 'Logged in as John Smith (johnsmith@acme.com).',
                  headingLink: 'Log out',
                }}
                onClickHeadingLink={() => console.log('Link clicked.')}
                onRequestClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}
            />
               </AlertContainer>
        ) : null}
    </IconSettings>
  )
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to use `useState`, also if you use `redux` you can integrate it with `useSelector` to get the inital state.

Example here:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function Example() { // or function Example(props) { , if you need to pass props to the component
    
    const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(true) // <-- initial state for "isOpen"

    const onRequestClose = () => {
        setOpen(false)
    }
    
    return (
        <>
        // ... code
        <SomeComponent
            onRequestClose={onRequestClose}
            // ... rest of code
        />
        // ... more code
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Better use onRequestClose = React.useCallback(...) Otherwise 'SomeComponent' is going to unnecessarily rerender many times

Answer (score 1):

Import state, use a classic function, define useState (  `const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);` ) and modify state using the function defined in useState.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Example = ()=> {

  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);

    return (
        <IconSettings iconPath="/assets/icons">
            {isOpen ? (
                <AlertContainer>
                    <Alert
                        dismissible
                        icon={<Icon category="utility" name="user" />}
                        labels={{
                            heading: 'Logged in as John Smith (johnsmith@acme.com).',
                            headingLink: 'Log out',
                        }}
                        onClickHeadingLink={() => {
                            console.log('Link clicked.');
                        }}
                        onRequestClose={() => {
                          setIsOpen(false);
                        }}
                    />
                </AlertContainer>
            ) : null }
        </IconSettings>
    );
                      }


export default Example;
```

Comment: Inline functions are ugly